# Cannot rename all the columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to rename all columns:

```
data.rename(columns={39:'Age','State-gov':'Workclas', 77516:'Final weight','Bachelors':'Education',
                     13:'Education number of years', 'Never-married':'Marital status', 
                     'Adm-clerical':'Occupation','Not-in-family':'Relationship','White':'Race', 
                     'Male':'Sex', 2174:'Capital gain', 0:'Capital loss', 40:'Hours per week',
                     'United-States':'Country of origin'}, inplace=True)
```

data.columns

Output:

```
Index(['39', ' State-gov', ' 77516', ' Bachelors', ' 13', ' Never-married',
       ' Adm-clerical', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', ' 2174', ' 0',
       ' 40', ' United-States', ' <=50K'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Most of your column names have leading spaces. Also, numbers are represented as string.

Comment: Your problem is dtypes.  You are trying to rename '39' a string with 39 an integer.  For example your first entry in your rename dictionary.  change `39:'Age'` to `'39':'Age'`.

Comment: Also, like Wouter states, it maybe wise to also, `df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()`  to remove whitespaces around strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()

data.rename(columns={'39':'Age','State-gov':'Workclas', '77516':'Final weight','Bachelors':'Education',
                     '13':'Education number of years', 'Never-married':'Marital status', 
                     'Adm-clerical':'Occupation','Not-in-family':'Relationship','White':'Race', 
                     'Male':'Sex', '2174':'Capital gain', '0':'Capital loss', '40':'Hours per week',
                     'United-States':'Country of origin'}, inplace=True)
```